# XAML+TextBox: Referencing text from resource file included in assembly

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

I know how to use an image from my assembly resources in XAML for the `Image` element:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/MyImage.png" />
```

But, how can I do it for the `Text` attribute of a `TextBox`?  Something similar to:

```
<TextBox Text="pack://application:,,,/MyTextFile.txt" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my current solution, but requires some code-behind:

```
Uri licenseUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyTextFile.txt", UriKind.Absolute);
StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(licenseUri);

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(info.Stream);
_textBox.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```